# How to deploy a web application in glass fish server

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, glassfish

I have started glass fish server as a windows service, can anyone please describe me how to deploy the application in the glass fish server

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you read f.e. http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/deployment/index.html#0.0.0.0.Deploying%20Applications|outline ?

Answer (score 6):

Several ways.

You can hook up your IDE (several of them support Glassfish).

You can use asadmin:

```
asadmin deploy youapp.war
```

You can use the Glassfish web console:

```
http://localhost:4848/ login/pw are likely admin/adminadmin
```

You can copy the WAR file to your glassfish_instal_dir/domain1/autodeploy directory.

I think that about covers the major ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to deploy the web application in the glass fish server,

In following [link](http://www.bullraider.com/java/ejb3/tutorials/39-how-to-deploy-in-glasshfish3) will porvide you the ways  to deploy the webservice in glass fish server

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish is a servlet container, and as such it works just like pretty much every other servlet container.  Just drop a valid deployable (typically a `.war` file) in the correct place, and the rest takes care of itself.

You can find more specific details (and some alternative deployment options) here:  https://blogs.oracle.com/chengfang/entry/seriously_deploying_apps_to_glassfish

Comment: GlassFish is much more than a servlet container.  It is a Java EE 6 application server that supports 28 specifications, one of which is the Servlet 3.0 specification.  I do understand what you are trying to say, but those new to web development that read this comment should know that GlassFish is oh so much more :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here goes [install,configure and Deploy application in Glassfish.](https://tazlambert.wordpress.com/2008/07/19/install-configure-and-deploy-war-application-in-glassfish/).Here deploy simple Hello world [application](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/821-0186/geyvr/index.html).